# Is it possible to call a test feature from a MockServer feature(matched) in KarateDSL?

Tags: karate, web-api-testing, mockserver

I'm trying to do something that I don't know if it is even remotely possible or not.

I've a Mock server, and I'd like that when it receives a given request, it "starts another test", calling a test feature. I tried some stuff, including the one bellow. But turns out that this Mockserver scenario do not respond.

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/ideas')
  * def xx = call read('SimpleStart.feature')
  * def response = $ideas.*
```

Is there an elegant way to make this work? AN workaround or a suggestion you can give me?
The use case is:
Perform tests, some tests, make some external services invoke the mockserver, and if the mockserver is requested it triggers other tests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Karate certainly isn't designed to do *that*. The pattern should be set up your mocks *and* tests from a Java "runner" for maximum control and that's what most teams do.

In short, "orchestrate" things from Java code.

That said, see if this gives you some other creative ideas: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Comment: Thanks. That is useful. I'll be creative :-D

Comment: From your knowledge, and just out of curiosity, is there any tool doing this out of the box?